# Why does a type assertion of "as any" fix this "No overload matches this call" error

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation in a React Native project with TypeScript. The code below is somewhat simplified - hopefully it makes my question clearer.

I have a file <navigator.tsx> which sets up the navigator and type checks it ...

```
// navigator.tsx
// ...
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native"
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack"
import {screen1, screen2} from "@screens"

export type StackNavigatorParams = {
    screen1: undefined
    screen2: undefined
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<StackNavigatorParams>()

const Navigator = (): ReactElement => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="screen1" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
                <Stack.Screen name="screen1" component={screen1}></Stack.Screen>
                <Stack.Screen name="screen2" component={screen2}></Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default Navigator
```

I then have a button component which expects a screen name as a prop (`nextPage`)

```
// ButtonComponent.tsx
// ...
import { StackNavigatorParams } from "@config/navigator";
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

type dummyButtonProps = {
    nextPage: "screen1" | "screen2";
};

export type StackNavigation = StackNavigationProp<StackNavigatorParams>;

const DummyButton = ({ nextPage }: dummyButtonProps) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigation>();
    return (
        // ...
        <Pressable
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate(nextPage); // <-- TypeScript error here, however, if I pass "nextPage as any" the error goes away.
            }}
        ></Pressable>
        // ...
    );
};
export default dummyButtonProps;
```

If I pass `nextPage` to `navigation.navigate(nextPage)` I get the lengthy error
`No overload matches this call.` specifically that `Argument of type '["screen1" | "screen2"]' is not assignable ...`.

However, if I pass `nextPage as any`, the error goes away and the type checking works as expected, that is, I can only pass the strings 'screen1' or 'screen2' as props - anything else gets a TypeScript error. Why does making this type assertion work? Is this the best way to handle the problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in the Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wQ3zvm

Comment: Type checking absolutely does NOT work as expected. `any`, for all intents and purposes, means "turn off type checking for this value altogether".

Comment: @EricHaynes that's the issue. I would think using `any` would mean I could pass in any prop (and therefore defeat the purpose of type checking) but I can only pass in the strings as specified by the type `dummyButtonProps`.